# Magura HS33 brake pads strongly pressed against rim, despite adjusting screw fully open. Too thick? Wrongly installed?

Tags: brakes, maintenance, rim-brake

I have a Magura HS33 with EVO2 mount bought some years ago.  I replaced my Magura HS33 brake pads.  I have turned the brake lever adjusting screw as far open as it gets, but the brake pads are too far inward.  Normally, when I turn the adjusting screw as far open as possible, there is about 1 mm space between the brake pads and the rim, but now there is no space at all, to the extent that the wheel is completely stuck.  Is it possible that the brake pads are too thick?  Or has a recent bike servicing messed up the brake installation?  Can I adjust the "reference width" of the brake cylinder somehow?

### Rear brake cylinder, overview

[image: Rear brake cylinder overview]]

### Brake pad pressed against rim, closeup

[image: Brake pad closeup]

### Brake lever adjusting screw closeup

[image: Brake lever adjusting screw]

Comment: Can you compare them to the old pads?   I don't recall the pad mountings - are there any washers that can be restacked ?

Comment: @Criggie I think they're identical, but I'll have a look tomorrow (I walked to work today). My suspicion is that the brake itself has been wrongly installed/serviced by a bike mechanic. I'll update the question with more information and some pictures tomorrow.

Comment: Potentially relevant question: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/44063/changing-magura-hs33-rim-brake-pads

Comment: @Criggie I've added some pictures.

Comment: Without further info we can't really guess if the pads are thicker than the previous ones, or the servicing put them too close, or the wheel shifted. In any case: tha pad looks fully retracted, so that's too close and you'll have to re-adjust (well, or shave down the pads, or measure all pads you have and try with the thinnest one there, or fix wheel alignment, or...)

Answer (score 3):

On the brake cylinder, the brake shoe holders are pushed too far toward the rim.  To pull them out:

- Unscrew the adapter screws (marked in red in the image);
- Pull the brake shoe holders away from the rim;
- Rescrew the adapter screws.

Repeat for the other side (the other side is quick release, so only has one adapter screw).  Magura recommends that there should be 1–1.5 mm space between the front of the brake pad and the edge of the rim.

[image: Photo with screws]

Comment: So its really just like hydraulic disk caliper centering, just with a bigger rotor.